# check if at least one file was uploaded php

Tags: php, forms

I have a form uploading multiple files:

```
 <?php
    $num_uploads = 3;
    $num = 0;
    while($num < $num_uploads)
    {
        echo '<div><input name="userfile[]" type="file" /></div>';
        $num++;
    }
 ?>
```

How do I check if at least one file was submitted with PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given how you're building the form, you'll have to account for a quirk in how PHP builds the files array.

```
foreach($_FILES['userfile']['error'] as $key => $err) {
    if ($err === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       ... got at least one file ...
    }
}
```

For some moronic reason, instead of storing each file's upload data in its own seperate sub-array within `$_FILES`, PHP opts to instead spread each seperate error/name/tmp_name/etc... across the regular categories like so:

```
$_FILES = array(
   'userfile' => array(
       'name' => array(
            0 => 'name of file #1'
            1 => "name of file #2'
            etc...
       ),
       'tmp_name' => array(
            0 => 'temp name of file #1'
            1 => 'temp name of file #2'
    etc.. etc... etc..
    )
);
```

A much more reasonable and understandable version would've been

```
$_FILES = array(
      'userfile' => array(
           0 => array(
              'name' => 'name of file #1'
              'tmp_name' => 'temp name of file #1'
              ...
           ),
           1 => array(
              'name' => 'name of file #2'
              'tmp_name' => 'temp name of file #2'
              ...
```

but, alas, PHP has yet again saddled the world with an overly convoluted and cumbersome stupidity.

Comment: It's not PHP, it's you. It's you naming your inputs. So, blame only yourself

Comment: I don't name my inputs like that. However, that doesn't change the fact that this is a moronic way of getting the file details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (count($_FILES)) {
    // at least 1 file
}
?>
```

Comment: You should really be checking `if (count($_FILES)>0)` instead.  While your answer is correct (any number not 0 converts to true), such implicit conversions can be confusing when skimming through code, and for new programmers to understand.

Comment: @Brad: True enough. The proper form also accounts for functions that return false, null, etc, which are all glopped together by the generic check. I guess I fall on the side of "if there is no other meaning, then shorter is more legible" side of "if (1 + 3 > 2)..." :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_FILES as $file){
    if($file['size'] > 0){
         $i++;
    }        
}
```

now if the `$i > 0` at least one file is uploaded. `$i` is the total numbers of file uploaded.

Comment: And what if the user wants to upload a zero-byte file? Check the `$file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK` instead, which is guaranteed to be true if an upload worked properly, regardless of file size.